# How to make Google speak British English?

Tags: google-search, localization

Google.co.uk and google.com spell *World* in IPA differently. But if you press the speak button, both pronounce it as /wərld/ (AmEng).

See screenshot from

[image: Google UK]

and from

[image: Google.com]

How can I make sure Google UK pronounces in British accent?

Comment: Which particular British accent did you have in mind - Cockney?  Geordie?  Scouse?

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ which British accent does not have **R** sound when you say **World** ?

Comment: I used to get RP pronunciations before, but now it gives me something really strange-sounding. It might be worth checking that your browser is set to send `en-GB` in the `Accept-Language` header, and not just `en`. (`Choose your preferred language for displaying web pages` in Firefox's settings)

Answer (score 9):

This is more of a workaround.

If you use the pronunciation function on https://translate.google.co.uk instead of just using the Google UK search bar, it will pronounce the word using the British accent.

https://translate.google.co.uk/#auto/en/world

Comment: This isn’t not working for me.

Comment: Thanks! translate.google.co.uk is British, translate.google.bg uses British too. translate.google.as is American English. And my browser languages are set to en-gb, bg-bg.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer, this works well: https://translate.google.co.uk/

Answer (score -3):

As of July 2021 there isn't a way to change Google Translator's English voice to British on desktop version, however there is a little hack to achieve this: visit https://translate.google.co.uk/ (notice it ends of .uk, thus United Kingdom) and it will use British speech.

Comment: I think this was an useful answer, although it lacks a bit of context and is not explaining why this different Google domain would help people to listen the translation output using British English accent.